# Sign out AWS amplify from all device except the current one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Can I (and how?) sign out AWS Amplify from all devices except the current one?

The following code signs out **all** devices, including the current one, and does not fulfill the job (but maybe it can be improved?):

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
Auth.signOut({ global: true }); // this will signout from all device including the current one
```

Comment: Please clarify what the question is?

Comment: @d1sh4 let say I have 10 device, and 9 device got stolen, I want revoke access those 9 device from 'not-stolen-device'. If I use code above, 'not-stolen-device' will also being logout, I expect 'not-stolen-device'(which I use now) to keep signed in.

Comment: @esdegan Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @SKhurana no sir